# Entity Framkework 'like' statement query

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

When I execute this query statement in oracle/sql developer it returns 3 rows as I expect.

```
select * from KIMYASAL k where lower(k.TURKCE_ADI) like '%lpg%'
```

Sample string:

> Petrol gazları, sıvılaştırılmış; Petrol gazı;   [[Ham petrolün
>   damıtılmasından elde edilen hidrokarbonların kompleks bir
>   kombinasyonu. C3 den C7 ye kadar olan aralıkta karbon sayısı ihtiva
>   eden hidrokarbonları ağırlıklı olarak ve yaklaşık olarak -40°C dan
>   80°C (-40°F dan 176°F a) a kadar aralıkta kaynayan türleri
>   içermektedir.]][LPG]

As you see, the sample string contains the string. The other 2 rows almost same..

When I debug my application this entity query return 0 rows:

```
context.Table.Where(k => k.TURKCE_ADI.Contains("lpg")).ToList();
```

Whats the problem with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `.ToLower()`:

```
context.Table.Where(k => k.TURKCE_ADI.ToLower().Contains("lpg")).ToList();
```